# How to ask someone about what happened

Tags: grammar, tense, past-tense

I want to ask my teacher if he checked the email/application which I sent him today.  How can I ask him?  What is actually the right way of asking it?

What I wrote is:

> Did you check the application ?

Or it may be

> Did you checked the application ?

and what when I ask him about response from head of department

> Did they respond for my admission ?

or

> Did they responded about my admission ?

Comment: Check out [this page on British Council website](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/clause-phrase-and-sentence/verb-patterns/verbs-questions-and-negatives). "For all verbs except be and have we use do/does and did with the base form of the verb to make Yes/No questions for the present simple and past simple forms". So your *Did you checked the application?* and *Did they responded about my admission?* are ungrammatical. Some alternatives: *"Have you received my application? I sent you an email yesterday."* *"What did he say?"* or "*Do you think I will be accepted?"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say **do *verb***, the word **do** changes to indicate tense and number, and the other ***verb*** takes its infinitive form. So, these are correct:

> Did you check the application?
>
> Did they respond regarding my admission?

And these are ungrammatical:

> <strike>Did you checked the application?</strike>
>
> <strike>Did they responded regarding my admission?</strike>

By the way, it's the same in declarative statements, where you say **do** to add emphasis:

> He checks the applications.
>
> He does check the applications.
>
> Does he check the applications?

Past tense:

> He checked the application.
>
> He did check the application.
>
> Did he check the application?

Comment: How about "Have you checked" and "Have they responded"? Don't you think they are even better than the past simple?

Comment: @fluffy Yes, I also think the perfect present is a little better than the simple past tense for these questions, although both are fine. I don't want to explain too many different things in the answer, though. Just getting used to the "meaningless 'do'" of English sounds like a major obstacle for someone learning English! It doesn't help that **have** takes the past participle where **do** takes the infinitive. It might be helpful to explain in a separate answer, though.

Comment: @BenKovitz thank you for the explanation , what actually i understand (and actually wants to know) is that we can not use second form with did like did he replied is wrong but did he reply is right , yes ?

Comment: @ARG Yes. "Did he replied?" is incorrect. "Did he reply?" is correct.